# Wrong html DIV width

Tags: html, css

I have 3 DIVs. The middle one contains two more DIVs. The two DIVs inside the middle div should appear over each other. I've made a sample about this concept: [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Aqd8u/2/)

```
<div style="background-color:blue; width:100%; height:100px;"></div>
<div style="width:100%; height:100px; background-color:green">
    <div style="background-color:red; width:100%; height:100px; position:absolute; z-index:0;"></div>
    <div style="background-color:yellow; width:100%; height:100px; position:absolute; z-index:1;"></div>
</div>
<div style="background-color:blue; width:100%; height:100px;"></div>
```

All the DIVs width is 100%, but I don't know why, but the middle div is bigger than the others. Why is that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Aqd8u/3/ Do you want something like that?

Comment: Add `position:relative` to the parent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The middle (yellow) one is larger because it has `position:absolute` set. This means that when it calculates its width (100%), the calculation is based on the nearest ancestor with `position` set. As no parent `div` has this, it takes it from the body element, which by default has padding/width defined, leading to the unanticipated width calculation.

You can rectify this with:

```
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Or by adding `position:relative` to a parent element. Though you will likely also want to remove `padding` from the `body`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aqd8u/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div style="background-color:blue; width:100%; height:100px;"></div>
<div style="width:100%; height:100px; background-color:green">
<div style="background-color:red; width:100%; height:100px;  z-index:0;"></div>
<div style="background-color:yellow; width:100%; height:100px;  z-index:1;"></div>
</div>
<div style="background-color:blue; width:100%; height:100px;"></div>
```